# Swift 4: multiple marker Google Map not display

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm developing an app that have a multiple location/marker.

I created a struct

```
let states = [
    State(name: "Zoo 1", long: 2.276537, lat: 102.2989),
    State(name: "Zoo 2", long: 2.2772141, lat: 102.2984333),
    // the other 51 states here...
]
```

and try a looping but the marker did not display

```
for state in states {
        let state_marker = GMSMarker()
        state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: state.lat, longitude: state.long)
        state_marker.title = state.name
        state_marker.snippet = "Hey, this is \(state.name)"
        state_marker.map = mapView
    }
```

when i do like below, it is working. but i know it's not a better way

```
let state_marker = GMSMarker()
    state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 2.276622, longitude: 102.2989)
    state_marker.title = "Zoo 1"
    state_marker.snippet = "Hey, this is Zoo 1"
    state_marker.map = mapView

    let state_marker1 = GMSMarker()
    state_marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 2.2772141, longitude: 102.2984333)
    state_marker1.title = "Zoo 2"
    state_marker1.snippet = "Hey, this is Zoo 2"
    state_marker1.map = mapView
```

Does anyone know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Please Check this Link [Same question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676823/create-multiple-markers-using-google-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You swapped the lat and Lon in first try , it works in second as longitude is 102.2989 , but in first you swapped them

```
 for state in states {
    let state_marker = GMSMarker()
    state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: state.lat, longitude: state.long)
    state_marker.title = state.name
    state_marker.snippet = "Hey, this is \(state.name)"
    state_marker.map = mapView
}
```

So change array to this

```
let states = [
    State(name: "Zoo 1", long:102.2989 , lat:  2.276537),
    State(name: "Zoo 2", long:102.2984333 , lat:  2.2772141),
    // the other 51 states here...
]
```

Edit :

Latitude measurements range from 0° to (+/–)90°. Longitude measures how far east or west of the prime meridian a place is located. The prime meridian runs through Greenwich, England. Longitude measurements range from 0° to (+/–)180°

Comment: Hmm...  I don't see any departure from his or hers.

Comment: look carefully to parameters and it's values he swapped them in the block that doesn't work

Comment: it's work. may i know, why we should swapped the longitude and latitude?