# Open google map and add multiple pins

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, url-scheme

To open the Google Maps app with a drop in pin, we use the code below:

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(self.location.coordinate.latitude),\(self.location.coordinate.longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
    }
}
```

This code is correct when working with one pin.

My question is, how do I add multiple pins?

Thanks in advance. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be supported, as per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003950/swift-4-multiple-marker-google-map-not-display

Comment: The above link is not helpful at all. That is not the same or relevant question.