# How to draw a google map marker depending on different id, Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my current project I get a response from api like this:

```
[
{
  "current_location" : [
    90.458456400000003,
    23.746056500000002
  ],
  "vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
  "_id" : "5a8fd7e50ed19875687dcf8c"
},
{
  "current_location" : [
    90.3727272,
    23.8216228
  ],
  "vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
  "_id" : "5a97f48edf192f6e54725c78"
},
{
  "current_location" : [
    90.397113300000001,
    23.778111200000001
  ],
  "vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
  "_id" : "5a980243df192f6e54725c85"
},
{
  "current_location" : [
    90.379659399999994,
    23.7221121
  ],
  "vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
  "_id" : "5a9a66586f27706a7a10783a"
},
{
  "current_location" : [
    90.400972899999999,
    23.872647400000002
  ],
  "vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
  "_id" : "5a9fff2e31eb895bc79f7ee0"
 }
]
```

Now I made a model class, later declared an array of that model type in different **ViewController** where its necessary.

```
var nearByFetchedVehicles = [nearByVehicleModel]()
```

Now as you can see in the response we get an **_id** of the vehicle. When I loop through **nearByFetchedVehicles** array, I want to create google map marker(of course some vehicle image would be used) for every **_id**. When we call the function again after say five seconds, I want to check if that **_id** exist, if that exist then I will check the latitude & longitude and move the marker accordingly, I have got the movement functionality covered already. This function will be called every five seconds so it continuously needs to check which **_id** has vanished and which **_id** is new. If any **_id** vanished which was previously there the the marker would be deleted, if new **_id** available new marker would be created. I need help to create marker & delete it with regards to **_id**.

```
 if let fetchedVehicle = result.value {

            if fetchedVehicle.isEmpty {
                print("No vehicle nearby")
            }

            self.nearByFetchedVehicles = fetchedVehicle
            print("nearByFetchedVehicles are:\(self.nearByFetchedVehicles)")
            self.mapView?.clear()

            for i in self.nearByFetchedVehicles  {

                // Need to create or delete marker here

                self.nearbyVehicleMovement(lat: i.lat!, lon: i.lon!, vehicleType: i.vehicleType!, vehicleID: i.vehicleID!)
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this! Might help you move a step forward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677559/4427884

Comment: I have tried that long before, here I need different approach.

Comment: You can simply create a custom class of `GMSMarker`, declare a string variable `_id` and its simple to distinguish on behalf of this property.

Comment: could you please show me an example ?

Comment: @ArafinRussell `class Marker: GMSMarker` like this. Which example you want to see? Class declaration, property declaration, deletion or addition?

Comment: @TheTiger why to use custom class when you can store the _id inside the userData property of GMSMarker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Set instead of Array. It has go `substracting` method which can easily works this your data.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var previousStr = """
[
{
"current_location" : [
90.458456400000003,
23.746056500000002
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a8fd7e50ed19875687dcf8c"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.3727272,
23.8216228
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a97f48edf192f6e54725c78"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.397113300000001,
23.778111200000001
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a980243df192f6e54725c85"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.379659399999994,
23.7221121
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a9a66586f27706a7a10783a"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.400972899999999,
23.872647400000002
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a9fff2e31eb895bc79f7ee0"
}
]
"""

var str = """
[
{
"current_location" : [
90.458456400000003,
23.746056500000002
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a8fd7e50ed19875687dcf8c"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.3727272,
23.8216228
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a97f48edf192f6e54725c78"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.397113300000001,
23.778111200000001
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a980243df192f6e54725c85"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.379659399999994,
23.7221121
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a9a66586f27706a7a10783a"
},
{
"current_location" : [
90.400972899999999,
23.872647400000002
],
"vehicle_type" : "BIKE",
"_id" : "5a9fff2e31eb895bc79f7ee0"
}
]
"""

struct Vehicle: Decodable, Hashable {
    let current_location: [Double]
    let vehicle_type: String
    let _id: String

    var hashValue: Int {
        return _id.hashValue
    }
}
let array: [Vehicle] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Vehicle].self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)
let set = Set<Vehicle>(array)

let previousArray: [Vehicle] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Vehicle].self, from: previousStr.data(using: .utf8)!)
let previousSet = Set<Vehicle>(previousArray)

print(previousSet)

let added = set.subtracting(previousSet)
let lost = previousSet.subtracting(set)

print(added)
print(lost)
```

Yields this:

> [__lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location: [90.3727272, 23.8216228],
>   vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id: "5a97f48edf192f6e54725c78"),
>   __lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location: [90.397113300000001, 23.778111200000001], vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id: "5a980243df192f6e54725c85"), __lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location:
>   [90.379659399999994, 23.7221121], vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id:
>   "5a9a66586f27706a7a10783a"), __lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location:
>   [90.400972899999999, 23.872647400000002], vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id:
>   "5a9fff2e31eb895bc79f7ee0"), __lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location:
>   [90.458456400000003, 23.746056500000002], vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id:
>   "5a8fd7e50ed19875687dcf8c")] added>>>>> [__lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location:
>   [90.400972899999999, 23.872647400000002], vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id:
>   "5a9fff2e31eb895bc79f7ee1")] lost>>>> [__lldb_expr_63.Vehicle(current_location:
>   [90.400972899999999, 23.872647400000002], vehicle_type: "BIKE", _id:
>   "5a9fff2e31eb895bc79f7ee0")]

In your case you can easily store previous data using `let previousSet = set`.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :

1. Every time you get the response from the server, clear the mapView using `mapView.clear()`. Then plot the markers again.
2. Assign _id as user data to each maker, as `marker.userData = _id`.
   Store the markers in an array and the loop through the markerArray. 
   Check whether the markers _id are present in the array from server. If it is not present remove the marker, as `marker.map = nil`. Other wise change the marker location using

   ```
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: <#T##CLLocationDegrees#>, longitude: <#T##CLLocationDegrees#>)
   ```

If the **_id** in the marker does not match to any **marker's userData** then create a new marker as:

```
let marker = GMSMarker.init(position: currentLocation)
marker.map = mapView
marker.userData = nearByFetchedVehicles[i]
```

**Hope this helps you.**

Comment: if I clear the mapView every time I get a response all the marker will be gone and I cant show a smooth animation, I want to show a vehicle moving from one place to another with smooth animation. Still I am trying your suggestion.

Comment: Then you can use the second way.